# Create calendar by code and add Permissions model in Liferay

Tags: calendar, liferay

I have Liferay 6.2 GA4...
I want to create a birthdays calendar by code, in a portlet... so I create a calendar in my portlet, with this code:

```
long calendarId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(Calendar.class.getName());
calendar =  CalendarLocalServiceUtil.createCalendar(calendarId);
calendar.setName(BIRTHDAYS_CALENDAR_NAME);
calendar.setGroupId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
calendar.setUserId(themeDisplay.getUserId());
calendar.setCreateDate(new Date());
calendar.setCompanyId(themeDisplay.getCompanyId());
calendar.setUserName(themeDisplay.getUser().getFullName());
calendar.setModifiedDate(new Date());
calendar.setCalendarResourceId(getCalendarDefault(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()).getCalendarResourceId());
calendar.setColor(6663561);
CalendarLocalServiceUtil.addCalendar(calendar);
```

**this works fine**, and the calendar gets created... but after that i am facing an issue...

If I try to set permissions to the calendar in the portlet (in the site), i get a blank page with an error in the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Permissioned model is null
```

so my question is:
how can i create the calendar with permissions? 
i want to create it with the default permissions, when you create a calendar in the site, this is what is shown, they are:

**Permissions**

**Viewable by: Site Members**

how can i do this??

thank you!!

**edit**

I asked this same question in the liferay forums, and didnt get an answer there... so im asking here, hopefully ill get an answer here :)

[same question](https://www.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/62911480)

Comment: I've seen that you've already asked that question [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/62911480). Please show some respect and add _always_ a link, when crossposting (see [this answer for an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site/141824#141824)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to do it, you just have to call the addModelResource method after creating the calendar..

```
ResourceLocalServiceUtil.addModelResources(calendar, serviceContext);
```

hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

you can call:

```
CalendarLocalServiceUtil.addCalendar(long userId, long groupId, long calendarResourceId, java.util.Map<java.util.Locale, java.lang.String> nameMap, java.util.Map<java.util.Locale, java.lang.String> descriptionMap, java.lang.String timeZoneId, int color, boolean defaultCalendar, boolean enableComments, boolean enableRatings, com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

it will create the resource permissions.

Fabio.

Comment: It's a friend of mine! Great liferay expert and i vote for him.

Comment: so call the addCalendar and pass all the params in the add calendar method? ok thank you, will try that!!

Comment: could not make it work using your method, i may have done something worng.. anyway i found another way, thank you!

Comment: I checked the addCalendar code, this answer should work! my guess is that I did something wrong.. ty!